# compilation errors : gtk+-2.0 gthread-2.0 not found

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to install Brackets.io on the Pi.
But the "create-project" step in Grunt is not very pleased with that try.
It tells me that it can't find the gtk+-2.0, nor the gthread-2.0 libraries and that I better check my PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variables.

When I do a "sudo apt-get install gtk+-2.0" it tells me that it'll use gir1.2-gtk-2.0 instead... so I guess I could change the appshell.gyp file so that it looks for gir instead of gtk+... no problem there... I hope at least.

But when I do a "sudo apt-get install gthread-2.0" it response immediately that it can't find that library... "Unable to locate package gthread-2.0".
Any idea's how to fix that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `-dev` packages in addition to the normal one if you want to compile against the library.

```
> apt-cache search gtk+-2.0
[...]
libgtk2.0-dev - development files for the GTK+ library
[...]
> apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Gthreads are part of glib, so the dev package should be:

```
> apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Comment: That's it !  Thank you soooooooooo much ! after I installed the libglib2.0-dev and the libgtk2.0-dev the compilation error disappeared.